# InfoPath: How to display a third column of a datasource?

Tags: infopath

I have an InfoPath 2007 browser-enabled form that has a datasource with three columns, let's say columns A, B, and C.  I have a dropdown that is keyed to column A and displays column B.  Column C contains some data that I want to display in an expression box, and that I also want to use in some data validation against another field on the form.  I'm looking for some help on how to reference that column C for displaying and use in validation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can access it by drilling down in the Data Source. If you don't see it, maybe its not a compatible data type (i.e. Multiline text).